# How to bind to a nested DataList using a property collection

Tags: c#, asp.net, datalist

I have seen (3) different examples of using a nested `DataList` or Repeater in ASP.NET, but all use a combination of a raw `DataTable/DataSet` and `CreateChildView` call to create the relationship between the outer and inner `DataList`.

Well since it is 2013 and not 2003, I have a class with the following structure:

```
public class Customer
{    
   public string FullName { get; set; }   
   public List<Orders> { get; set; }   
}
```

The idea is that the `Orders` collection is what is bound as the `DataSource` for the *inner, nested* `DataList`. The problem is I can't seem to figure out how to set up the relationship in the code for the binding. The inner DataList is actually *not* directly accessable in code via Intellisense since it is nested under the main DataList. Here is the typical code in the `ItemDataBound` event to find the inner `DataList` and assign its `DataSource` using `CreateChildView`:

```
protected void outerRep_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
    {
        DataRowView drv = e.Item.DataItem as DataRowView;
        DataList innerDataList = e.Item.FindControl("innerDataList") as DataList;
        innerDataList.DataSource = drv.CreateChildView("OrdersRelation");
        innerDataList.DataBind();
    }
}
```

"OrdersRelation" in all the examples I see is set up like the following:

```
// Attach the relationship to the dataSet
ds.Relations.Add(new DataRelation("OrdersRelation", ds.Tables[0].Columns["OrderID"],
ds.Tables[1].Columns["OrderID"]));
outerDataList.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
outerDataList.DataBind();
```

Obviously this is not applicable as I'm using a strongly typed object with a collection property of 'Orders' on it.

How can I achieve the same result and bind my inner `DataList` to my `Orders` collection property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out; just took a bit to get back in the ole' ASP.NET server controls mode ;)

The idea is to still use the `ItemDataBound` event, but inspect for both `Item` and `AlternatingItem` along with casting the `DataItem` to the `CustomerObject`. Then I proceeded to use the original collection bound to the `DataList` I had stored in session and use a quick `Find()` to get the proper object pulled back out. Once that's narrowed down, I can use it's `.Orders` collection to bind to the inner `DataList.DataSource` property. It works like a charm:

```
protected void ui_dlst_ETLMainInformation_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{

   if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
   {
      Customer c = e.Item.DataItem as Customer;
      DataList innerDataList = e.Item.FindControl("innerDataListControl") as DataList;

      List<Customers> customers = ((IList)Session["CustomersCollection"]).Cast<Customers>().ToList();

      Customer customer = customers.Find(ct => ct.ID == c.ID);

      innerDataList.DataSource = customer.Orders;
      innerDataList.DataBind();
    }
}
```